# Wrong font size showing for toolbar title and subtitle

Tags: java, android, textview, android-toolbar

After implementing a title and subtitle for my toolbar, the wrong font size is used for some reason. What needs to be done in order to fix this?

[image]

**Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar customToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbarC);
        customToolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E21836"));

        TextView mTitle = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        mTitle.setText("Hello World");
        mTitle.setSingleLine(true);

        TextView mSubtitle = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_subtitle);
        mSubtitle.setText("Hello World");
        mSubtitle.setSingleLine(true);
    }
}
```

**toolbarC.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarC"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_text_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: i think there is a problem in your toolbar id just cross check in xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem and have solved it. There was a hidden duplicate of the toolbar text views within my project and the duplicate title & subtitle were what was shown to me when deploying my app.

Comment: Could you explane just what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

add textSize to each textViews. Try like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar_2lines"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_text_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line, probably it's using app_name as title
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
and try using dp instead of sp

Answer (score -1):

Increase Toolbar's Height to `?actionBarSize`